# Updates were rejected, because the tip of your current branch is behind… Not true

Tags: git, version-control

> Updates were rejected, because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.

I know, how to resolve it, however, the subject of my question is different.

1. I created two branches
2. I added one commit to each of them
3. I pushed them into remote repository
4. I rebased **second-branch** into `first-branch`
5. I pushed both branches to remote repository
6. *Success*

---

1. I created two branches
2. I added one commit to each of them
3. I pushed them into remote repository
4. I rebased `first-branch` into **second-branch**
5. I pushed both branches to remote repository
6. *I got that error*

How come remote repository is ahead of me (I am behind), when I have 2 local commits and only 1 remote commit?

What I am missing? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

> What does "I rebased into second-branch into first-branch" mean? That you rebased second-branch onto the tip of first-branch?

Sorry, I did not pay attention to my grammar for a while. I corrected it

---

*"I rebased second-branch into first-branch"* means

> git checkout first-branch
>
> git rebase second-branch

Comment: What do these two numbered list represent? The first one shouldn't have succeeded.

Comment: What does "I rebased into second-branch into first-branch" mean? That you rebased second-branch onto the tip of first-branch?

Comment: Sorry, my grammar fault. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After the first push your local and remote branches look like this:

```
first-branch   A
second-branch  B
```

After the rebase of first-branch onto second-branch, they look like this:

```
first-branch   B-A'
second-branch  B
```

When you attempt to push first-branch, your local branch is two commits ahead of the remote (`B` and `A'`) and the remote is one commit ahead of your local branch (`A`).

Comment: I had some errors in the post. However I think you get my point. I still do not understand the last sentence "remote is one commit ahead of your local branch". Look, I had one commit in branch R2, I pushed it into remote repository. So now, they are equal `remote R2 (1c) == local R2 (1c)`. I did rebase R1 onto R2. so now it is `remote R2 (1c) < local R2 (1c + 1c)`

Comment: After rebasing R1 onto R2, R2 is untouched and pushing it to the remote will be a no-op. A push of R1, however, will be a non fast-forward update since the remote has one commit that the local branch doesn't have (`A`, using the terminology of my answer). Yes, your local branch has `A'` but that's not the same commit. The rewritten commit `A'` might apply the same delta as `A` but that's irrelevant.